# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'customerId')

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I want each click on the download button to increase the number of downloads by 1, but I have this error

customer.js:

```
exports.numberDownload = async (req, res)=>{
  try {
    const customer =  await Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.customerId)
    if(customer.countDownload<5){
      await Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.customerId, {$inc:{countDownload: +1}}, {new: true})
    res.send({message: 'downloaded succefully'})
    }
    else {
      res.status(400).send({message: "You can't download only five per month"})
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: error.message || 'some error occured'
    }); 
  }
}
```

book-details.html:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="card mb-3 col-sm-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img [src]="book.photo" alt="book" class="img-fluid rounded-start" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">{{book.title | titlecase}}</h3>
          <p class="card-text">{{book.author | titlecase}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">
            {{book.description | slice:0:100}}
            <span *ngIf="book.description.length > 100">...</span>
          </p>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="download()" [disabled]="((countDownload >= 5) || (typeCustomer == 'Normal')) ? true : false">
            <a href= "{{book.contentLink}}" target="_blank"
            download="{{book.title}}"
           >Download</a>
           </button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookClientService {
  baseURL='http://localhost:3000/api/v1/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBooks(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}BooksCustomer`);
  }

  getBookById(idBook: any){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}BookCustomer/${idBook}`);
   }

   countDownload(customerId: any, data: any){
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}download/${customerId}`, data);
   }
}
```

component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BookClientService } from 'src/app/client/list-books/bookClient.service';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/views/customers/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-details',
  templateUrl: './book-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-details.component.scss']
})
export class BookDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  book: any;
  idBook: any;
  idCustomer: any;
  countDownload: any;
  typeCustomer: any;
  constructor(private bookClientService: BookClientService, private customerService: CustomerService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.idBook = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.bookClientService.getBookById(this.idBook).subscribe(response => this.book = response);
    
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
    let decodedToken: any = jwt_decode(token);
    this.countDownload = decodedToken.countDownload;
    this.typeCustomer = decodedToken.type;
    this.idCustomer = decodedToken.customerId;
  }

  download(){
 this.bookClientService.countDownload(this.idCustomer, this.idBook).subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
 }
}
```

c'est un projet de gestion de librairie
le client abonné peut faire 5 téléchargement dens un mois par contre le client normal ne peut pas téléchargé

Comment: which line is the error pointing to? What is it trying to read the customerID of? What's the value of that variable?

Comment: In the last line of the `ngOnInit()` method you read the customerId property, where did you define it ?
`this.idCustomer = decodedToken.customerId;`